# High res monthly satellite maps including ice cover

Tags: raster, data, satellite

I have some old month by month NASA satellite maps showing the world in 2004 at 5400x2700px. I've noticed NASA has newer cleaner versions of these maps at http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=BlueMarbleNG-TB&date=2004-12-01, however the maximum resolution is only 3600x1800. Also both map sets have ice cover removed.

Are there any month by month raster satellite world map sets out there with a resolution of 5400x2700px or higher and including ice cover?

Answer (score 2):

There is 6.25km ice concentration data from passive microwave remote sensing in two parts:

1. 2002-2011 http://icdc.zmaw.de/1/daten/cryosphere/seaiceconcentration-asi-amsre.html
2. 2012- present http://www.iup.uni-bremen.de:8084/amsr2/

Also, there is 25km data from NSIDC since 1978, with very few gaps

1. Archived: http://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0051.html
2. Near real time: http://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0081.html

Both of these products come in Polar Stereographic grids, separate for the northern and southern hemispheres. You'd need to process them into global long-lat grids, but that's reasonably straightforward.

Comment: There are similar maps at http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=NISE_D already in Equirectangular form. I'm assuming if I want maps like I'm asking for I'll need to composite them myself and make educated guesses what the ice should look like if photographed from space?